# LANGUAGE INTERFACE WAS CALLED WHEN THE CONNECTING ENVIRONMENT WAS NOT ESTABLISHED

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe

When the COBOL program mapped to a DB2 user defined function, in one of our apps is triggered. It fails with the SQLCODE = -927 & SQLSTATE=51006. There is explanation that Language interface was called without establishing connecting environment. But can someone please advise how to solve this.

Should I be using any specific compiler options or bind parameters while compiling the above mentioned COBOL program which gets triggered by DB2 function.

Comment: Is this batch or Cics or IMS DC or Batch IMS DB program. If batch can you provide the JCL. Most sites standard procedures for Compiling/linking DB2 programs. Most sites have JCL procedures for running DB2 Barch programs, other environments there are differences in the link-edit. Have a look at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n927.html and ask around.

Comment: Is this a stored procedure?  Did you link the program to use DSNRLI?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your batch components includes JCL and Cobol + DB2 and you are trying to execute the Cobol program in the job like PGM = Cobol program name but since your are executing a DB2 component, you need to execute the program via utility like IKJEFT01 and it will solve your problem.

Regards,
Anbu